# Python to Swift, While Loop.

Tags: python, swift, while-loop

I am working on re-writing some code from python to swift and I am not sure if this while loop is correct. The code below shows the while loop in python and I have re-written it in swift further below. On running the code I seem to get a frozen simulator and with a little debugging, the while loop seems to be fine. Maybe I'm missing something. Any insights?

```
    #parents = [[Int]]
    #pop = [[Int]]
    parents_length = len(parents)
    desired_length = len(pop) - parents_length
    children = []
    while len(children) < desired_length:
        male = randint(0, parents_length-1)
        female = randint(0, parents_length-1)
        if male != female:
            male = parents[male]
            female = parents[female]
            half = len(male) / 2
            child = male[:half] + female[half:]
            children.append(child)
```

Code in Swift

```
        //newParents = [[Int]]
        //pop = [[Int]]

private func randomIntergerInRange(low:Int, high:Int) -> Int {
        let randomGeneratedNumber = low + Int(arc4random()) % (high - low);
        return Int(randomGeneratedNumber)
    }
        let parents_length = newParents.count
        let desired_length = pop.count - parents_length
        var children : [[Int]] = []

    while children.count < desired_length {

        let male = randomIntergerInRange(0, high: parents_length - 1)
        let female = randomIntergerInRange(0, high: parents_length - 1)

        if male != female {
            var males = newParents[male] //This should return an individual from the array of parents
            var females = newParents[female] ////This should return an individual from the array of parents
            let half = males.count / 2


            let child = males[0..<half] + females[half..<females.count]
            children.append(Array(child))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```
import UIKit

var newParents : [[Int]] = [[]]
var pop : [[Int]] = [[]]

private func randomIntergerInRange(low:Int, high:Int) -> Int {
    let randomGeneratedNumber = low + Int(arc4random()) % (high - low);
    return Int(randomGeneratedNumber)
}

let parents_length = newParents.count
let desired_length = pop.count - parents_length
var children : [[Int]] = []

while children.count < desired_length {
    let male = randomIntergerInRange(0, parents_length - 1)
    let female = randomIntergerInRange(0, parents_length - 1)

    if male != female {
        var males = newParents[male] //This should return an individual from the array of parents
        var females = newParents[female] ////This should return an individual from the array of parents
        let half = males.count / 2

        let child = males[0..<half] + females[half..<females.count]
        children.append(Array(child))
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and how it addresses the problem.  I'm not trying to nitpick; I just can't see it.

Comment: This is the same as the code I posted and does not work unfortunately.